# Magento 2 add condition filter with collection

Tags: magento2

I need to build a query like

```
select * from table_name where '2008' >= substr(table_name.field_name,7,4);
```

in this query **2008** is the dynamic value.
I need this to be built using Magento collection addFieldToFilter function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can inject collection in construct

```
public function __construct(\vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory){
$this->collectionFactory=$collectionFactory;
}

public function customMethod(){
$collection=$this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->getSelect()->where(''2008' >= substr(table_name.field_name,7,4)');
         }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working now

Comment: need a little more help @Rutvee Sojitra

Comment: @MandarParbate please add new question so i not I any other Can surely help you

Comment: check the ques : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276332/magento-2-custom-table-collection-conditions

Answer (score 0):

using OR condition in addFieldToFilter

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(['status','status'],[['nin'=>$allnonactiveorderstatus],['null'=>true]])
```