# Magento 2 Custom table collection Conditions

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I'm facing an issue with the dynamic parameters for the filter

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('field_name');
```

If I have below code it works fine if the parameter is **2008**, but if parameter is passed like **2008'**, I get an mysql error.

```
$collection->getSelect()->where($carYear.' >= substr(tyreld,7,4)');
```

> with paramter **2008** The query is like: WHERE (2008 >= substr(tyreld,7,4)) with no error
>
> with paramter **2008'** The query is like: WHERE (2008' >= substr(tyreld,7,4)) This throughs
>   an mysql syntax error

But if I tried the below code with no conditions it gives me no error.

```
->addFieldToFilter('tyreld', array('gteq' => $carYear));
```

How can we handle this type of issues.

Comment: actually not getting your line " if the parameter is 2008, but if parameter is passed like 2008'," can you please explain

Comment: @RutveeSojitra I have updated my que

Comment: so your column name is 2008'  ?

Comment: no, it's the value

Comment: add your db screenshot or add db structure  and let me know what you want to actually get

Comment: basically, I need to handle the SQL errors. The Magento function addFieldToFilter handles the parameter if I pass the parameter like 2008 & 2008'.But if I use getSelect()->where it does not handle the parameters.

Comment: this function addFieldToFilter treat this parameter 2008' as 2008\'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

The `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

you can also try below code:

$result  = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s','',$value);

Comment: can you add the code in magento 2 way?

Comment: updated my code, I dont thing that is there any default functionality provided by magento because magento using zend db adapter. you can use above php code.